# How can I merge files line by line in the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, merge, paste

In dos, is there a way to merge a set of files so that for instance

#### 1.txt

a
b
c

and

#### 2.txt

1
2
3

becomes

#### merged.txt

a 1
b 2
c 3

Just like the paste command on *nix systems

Comment: dos as in "dos - operating system" or as in "windows cmd.exe" ?

Comment: cygwin works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you'll need to merge the lines with a program, or a scripting language, like Python.

**Update:** Look at [these Win ports of GNU utilities](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), it includes paste (.exe)

Comment: Too bad. Sukcs not to have Linux at work... :p

Comment: @Paul: install http://cygwin.com/setup.exe

Answer (score 1):

If the data reasonably simple, you could do it with Excel. Or you could download OpenOffice and do it in Calc, but the method in Calc is a pain. (You need to paste the data into two columns then merge them with the "Concatenate" function, in formula form (e.g. concatenate(Row1; row2;))

Answer (score 1):

Definitely agree that a port of Unix tools or a scripting language is the way to go (although VBScript or Powershell are probably more convenient choices than Python for Windows users), but merging two files **IS** possible in DOS:-

```
@ECHO OFF

REM .bat to merge 1.txt and 2.txt

GOTO :Main

:StartMerge
    SET /P _a=<%1
    SET /P _b=<%2

    ECHO %_a% %_b%

    DEL %1 %2

    GOTO :EndMerge

:CleanUp
    SET _LinesIn1=
    SET _LinesIn2=

    SET _a=
    SET _b=

    GOTO :EOF

:Main
    SET _LinesIn1=0
    SET _LinesIn2=0

    FOR /F "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%i IN ('findstr /n "^" 1.txt') DO (
        ECHO.%%j>_c1n%%i
        SET /A _LinesIn1+=1
    )

    FOR /F "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%i IN ('findstr /n "^" 2.txt') DO (
        ECHO.%%j>_c2n%%i
        SET /A _LinesIn2+=1
    )

    IF %_LinesIn1% NEQ %_LinesIn2% (
        ECHO Cannot merge files; mismatched line count:-
        ECHO   1.txt - %_LinesIn1% lines
        ECHO   2.txt - %_LinesIn2% lines

        DEL _c*

        GOTO :CleanUp
    )

    FOR /L %%n IN (1, 1, %_LinesIn1%) DO (
        CALL :StartMerge _c1n%%n _c2n%%n

        :EndMerge
        REM No-op to avoid ") was unexpected at this time." error
    )

    GOTO :CleanUp
```

File under "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should." :-)

Answer (score 0):

Merge 2 text files:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('find /c /v "" ^< test2.txt') do set /a n=%i<nul
for /l %a in (1,1,%n%) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('find /v /n "" ^< test1.txt ^| find "[%a]"') do (
for /f "tokens=*" %j in ('find /v /n "" ^< test2.txt ^| find "[%a]"') do (
set a=%i
set b=%j
set a=!a:*]=!
set b=!b:*]=!
echo:!a! !b!>>merged.txt
)))
```

test1.txt:

```
a
b
c
```

test2.txt:

```
1
2
3
```

merged.txt:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Tested on Win 10 CMD